# Cohomology of sheaves on $X \cup_{Z} Y$

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology, schemes, derived-categories

I am in the following situation, I have two schemes $X$, $Y$ and two closed immersions $Z \rightarrow Y$, $Z \rightarrow X$. Everything is smooth. I am interested in calculating morphisms in the derived category of $X \cup_{Z} Y$ between two complexes, one of which is in the image of the pushforward via one of the two closed immersions $X \rightarrow X \cup_Z Y$, $Y \rightarrow X \cup_Z Y$. I know that there is a short exact sequence
$$
 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X \cup_Z Y} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{Y} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Z} \rightarrow 0
$$
but this doesn't help very much. It would be very helpful if $X$ and $Y$ were cut in $X \cup_Z Y$ by some vector bundles, but I don't think that's possible as $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and $X \cup_Z Y$ might be not. Is there any general technique one tries to apply in such situation? Any help would be very appriaceted.

Comment: Lurie's SAG, section 16.2 will help you a lot.

Comment: @Federico : it would somehow be easier to answer to your question if you tell us what are the two objects in $D^b(X \cup_{Z} Y)$ you are considering.

Comment: @Libli for example, I'm interested in the endomorphism algebra in the derived category of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ and the same for $Y$. Also, I'm interested in the derived dual of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ and $Y$.

Comment: @crystalline Thank you for the advice. However, I had a look at SAG and I don't see how it helps with respect to the calculations I am trying to do (the ones in the previous comment).

Comment: @Federico : There is a notion of Diagram of schemes (which is basically the data of the two arrows from $X$ and $Y$ to $X \cup_{Z} Y$) and Lipman-Hashimoto wrote a book on Grothendieck duality for such diagrams.

Comment: In particular there is a whole chapter (page 377-383) on right adjoint for Diagram of schemes. It is possible that you may extract from there the computations you need.